# Saving friendship in the database. Social networking service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

At present, I am currently storing in this way in the database

```
id  from_id  to_id
1     1        2
2     2        1
```

I write down such friendships in this way

```
this.friendshipRepository.save(new FriendshipEntity(fromUser.get(), toUser.get()));
this.friendshipRepository.save(new FriendshipEntity(toUser.get(), fromUser.get()));
```

a when I remove

```
this.friendshipRepository.delete(this.friendshipRepository.findOneByFromUserAndToUser(fromUser.get(), toUser.get()));
this.friendshipRepository.delete(this.friendshipRepository.findOneByFromUserAndToUser(toUser.get(), fromUser.get()));
```

I have to do everything twice. It is a little inconvenient.

Do you know any better ways to store friendship between users in the database?

Answer (score 1):

if you consider friendship is symmetric, then an option is to rewrite your database schema.
instead of

```
id  from_id  to_id
```

it could be

```
id  lower_id  higher_id
```

so a given friendship has a unique entry in the database, and you can remove a friendship with a single query.

the downside is that if you want to list someone friends, you have to look up this someone in **both** `lower_id` and `higher_id`

Comment: I agree with Gilles comment - you either have more time in creating and removing records, or more time in querying them. Which is the most used in your system? I prefer your original approach where the data creation time takes slightly longer, but leads to easier/faster querying.